# Breaker panel questions with dryers involved

Tags: electrical, dryer

There are two different breaker panels where I live and in my apartment hallway my one light switch controls my washer and dryer and also the switch in my control panel, however, my neighbor's upstairs their dryer somehow is connected to my breaker panel and controls their dryer by flipping the switch in the panel. How does that work? We each have our own for our own apartment.

Comment: It sounds like someone mis-wired the apartment(s). Maybe [edit] in some photos so we know what you mean by "switch" and "control panel" etc.  If you need to switch browsers or devices to post photos, make sure to register your account (tie it to a username/password, Facebook, Google login etc. so you can log in from the other device and it knows it's you.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the various devices involved please?

Comment: Do you and your neighbors each have separate meters for electric service?